# Create data frame from json step exaction history aws

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, aws-step-functions

I have got step function execution history in JSON format

```
[{
    "timestamp": "2022-07-18T13:03:03.346000+00:00",
    "type": "ExecutionFailed",
    "id": 3,
    "previousEventId": 2,
    "executionFailedEventDetails": {
        "error": "States.Runtime",
        "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'Workflow Choice state' (entered at the event id #2). Invalid path '$.contributor_id': The choice state's condition path references an invalid value."
    }
}, {
    "timestamp": "2022-07-18T13:03:03.306000+00:00",
    "type": "ChoiceStateEntered",
    "id": 2,
    "previousEventId": 0,
    "stateEnteredEventDetails": {
        "name": "Workflow Choice state",
        "input": "{\n    \"Comment\": \"Insert your JSON here\"\n}",
        "inputDetails": {
            "truncated": false
        }
    }
}, {
    "timestamp": "2022-07-18T13:03:03.252000+00:00",
    "type": "ExecutionStarted",
    "id": 1,
    "previousEventId": 0,
    "executionStartedEventDetails": {
        "input": "{\n    \"Comment\": \"Insert your JSON here\"\n}",
        "inputDetails": {
            "truncated": false
        },
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::asdfg:role/step-all"
    }
}]
```

We want to create a view like below
[image]

The issue is i am not able to create executionFailedEventDetails ,stateEnteredEventDetails,executionStartedEventDetails as new row .
It comes in first row only .

**Step** column is the name in the stateEnteredEventDetails

This is what i am doing

```
import json

import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

raw = r"""[{
    "timestamp": "2022-07-18T13:03:03.346000+00:00",
    "type": "ExecutionFailed",
    "id": 3,
    "previousEventId": 2,
    "executionFailedEventDetails": {
        "error": "States.Runtime",
        "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'Workflow Choice state' (entered at the event id #2). Invalid path '$.contributor_id': The choice state's condition path references an invalid value."
    }
}, {
    "timestamp": "2022-07-18T13:03:03.306000+00:00",
    "type": "ChoiceStateEntered",
    "id": 2,
    "previousEventId": 0,
    "stateEnteredEventDetails": {
        "name": "Workflow Choice state",
        "input": "{\n    \"Comment\": \"Insert your JSON here\"\n}",
        "inputDetails": {
            "truncated": false
        }
    }
}, {
    "timestamp": "2022-07-18T13:03:03.252000+00:00",
    "type": "ExecutionStarted",
    "id": 1,
    "previousEventId": 0,
    "executionStartedEventDetails": {
        "input": "{\n    \"Comment\": \"Insert your JSON here\"\n}",
        "inputDetails": {
            "truncated": false
        },
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::asdfg:role/step-all"
    }
}]"""


data = json.loads(raw, strict=False)
data = pd.json_normalize(data)
# print(data.to_csv(), index=False)
print(tabulate(data, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
data.to_csv('file.csv',encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

and the output is

```
+----+----------------------------------+--------------------+------+-------------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|    | timestamp                        | type               |   id |   previousEventId | executionFailedEventDetails.error   | executionFailedEventDetails.cause                                                                                                                                                                 | stateEnteredEventDetails.name   | stateEnteredEventDetails.input         |   stateEnteredEventDetails.inputDetails.truncated | executionStartedEventDetails.input     |   executionStartedEventDetails.inputDetails.truncated | executionStartedEventDetails.roleArn   |
|----+----------------------------------+--------------------+------+-------------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------|
|  0 | 2022-07-18T13:03:03.346000+00:00 | ExecutionFailed    |    3 |                 2 | States.Runtime                      | An error occurred while executing the state 'Workflow Choice state' (entered at the event id #2). Invalid path '$.contributor_id': The choice state's condition path references an invalid value. | nan                             | nan                                    |                                               nan | nan                                    |                                                   nan | nan                                    |
|  1 | 2022-07-18T13:03:03.306000+00:00 | ChoiceStateEntered |    2 |                 0 | nan                                 | nan                                                                                                                                                                                               | Workflow Choice state           | {                                      |                                                 0 | nan                                    |                                                   nan | nan                                    |
|    |                                  |                    |      |                   |                                     |                                                                                                                                                                                                   |                                 |     "Comment": "Insert your JSON here" |                                                   |                                        |                                                       |                                        |
|    |                                  |                    |      |                   |                                     |                                                                                                                                                                                                   |                                 | }                                      |                                                   |                                        |                                                       |                                        |
|  2 | 2022-07-18T13:03:03.252000+00:00 | ExecutionStarted   |    1 |                 0 | nan                                 | nan                                                                                                                                                                                               | nan                             | nan                                    |                                               nan | {                                      |                                                     0 | arn:aws:iam::asdfg:role/step-all       |
|    |                                  |                    |      |                   |                                     |                                                                                                                                                                                                   |                                 |                                        |                                                   |     "Comment": "Insert your JSON here" |                                                       |                                        |
|    |                                  |                    |      |                   |                                     |                                                                                                                                                                                                   |                                 |                                        |                                                   | }                                      |                                                       |                                        |
+----+----------------------------------+--------------------+------+-------------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

The Details column 5th column is dynamic like all columns currently i have given example of only 3 event but it can go up to any number .

Final Expected Output

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want the final output to be?

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow I have attached the screen shot .Basically last column value should come under details column .Details  columns can be created and value should come under this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `file.json`:

```
[{
    "timestamp": "2022-07-18T13:03:03.346000+00:00",
    "type": "ExecutionFailed",
    "id": 3,
    "previousEventId": 2,
    "executionFailedEventDetails": {
        "error": "States.Runtime",
        "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'Workflow Choice state' (entered at the event id #2). Invalid path '$.contributor_id': The choice state's condition path references an invalid value."
    }
}, {
    "timestamp": "2022-07-18T13:03:03.306000+00:00",
    "type": "ChoiceStateEntered",
    "id": 2,
    "previousEventId": 0,
    "stateEnteredEventDetails": {
        "name": "Workflow Choice state",
        "input": "{\n    \"Comment\": \"Insert your JSON here\"\n}",
        "inputDetails": {
            "truncated": false
        }
    }
}, {
    "timestamp": "2022-07-18T13:03:03.252000+00:00",
    "type": "ExecutionStarted",
    "id": 1,
    "previousEventId": 0,
    "executionStartedEventDetails": {
        "input": "{\n    \"Comment\": \"Insert your JSON here\"\n}",
        "inputDetails": {
            "truncated": false
        },
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::asdfg:role/step-all"
    }
}]
```

Doing

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('file.json')
df = df.melt(['timestamp', 'type', 'id', 'previousEventId'], var_name='step', value_name='details').dropna()
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Output (Markdown was just the easiest for me to show all):

```
| timestamp                        | type               |   id |   previousEventId | step                         | details                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
|:---------------------------------|:-------------------|-----:|------------------:|:-----------------------------|:------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2022-07-18 13:03:03.346000+00:00 | ExecutionFailed    |    3 |                 2 | executionFailedEventDetails  | {'error': 'States.Runtime', 'cause': "An error occurred while executing the state 'Workflow Choice state' (entered at the event id #2). Invalid path '$.contributor_id': The choice state's condition path references an invalid value."} |
| 2022-07-18 13:03:03.306000+00:00 | ChoiceStateEntered |    2 |                 0 | stateEnteredEventDetails     | {'name': 'Workflow Choice state', 'input': '{\n    "Comment": "Insert your JSON here"\n}', 'inputDetails': {'truncated': False}}                                                                                                          |
| 2022-07-18 13:03:03.252000+00:00 | ExecutionStarted   |    1 |                 0 | executionStartedEventDetails | {'input': '{\n    "Comment": "Insert your JSON here"\n}', 'inputDetails': {'truncated': False}, 'roleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::asdfg:role/step-all'}                                                                                            |
```

Comment: I am already getting this .I need last column under details columns

Comment: All details columns is linked to ID .executionStartedEventDetails is for id 1 and stateEnteredEventDetails for id 2 likewaise

Comment: So the out out i am not able to create thats why not able to paste it here .But Last row is details is getting displayed like individual columns that i need to be like vertical columns

Comment: sorry about that i am, creating view in table will share soon

Comment: I have updated the question with expected output .Can you please have a look now

Comment: @AtharvThakur This is very close to your desired format, is that close enough?

Comment: Yes it is close ...Let me check few more things and then i will confirm but your code is not working for me ...Getting erros like `TypeError: melt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'val_name'`

Comment: I can force it back together with a few more steps if needed.

Comment: I think even what you have displayed is better ...But i am getting error

Comment: Fix `value_name`, I had it typed wrong before.